# Infinispan - Transaction Manager over Hot Rod Client API

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, transactions, infinispan

I am using infinispan 12.0.2 FINAL over hot rod client but I am unable to get the transaction manager to work.

Here is how I am configuring my caches:

```
ConfigurationBuilder builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
    builder.clustering().cacheMode(CacheMode.DIST_SYNC);
    builder.locking().isolationLevel(IsolationLevel.REPEATABLE_READ);
    builder.transaction().lockingMode(LockingMode.PESSIMISTIC);
    builder.transaction().transactionMode(org.infinispan.transaction.TransactionMode.TRANSACTIONAL);
    builder.transaction().transactionManagerLookup(org.infinispan.client.hotrod.transaction.lookup.GenericTransactionManagerLookup.getInstance());          
rcm.administration().withFlags(CacheContainerAdmin.AdminFlag.VOLATILE).getOrCreateCache(cacheName,
                builder.build());
```

But everytime I try to access the transaction by remoteCachne.getTransactionManager, I am getting a null for transaction Manager.
I am not able to figure out the issue. Please help in this.

Answer (score 2):

After enabling transactions in the server cache, you need to enable transactions in the remote cache as well.

Check the [Hot Rod Documentation](https://infinispan.org/docs/12.0.x/titles/hotrod_java/hotrod_java.html#hr_transactions_config_client) how to do it.

Comment: Yes, even after doing that I have got that cache is not transactional.

Comment: Do you have a reproducer?

Comment: It looks like `LockObtainFailedException` is from Lucene and, unfortunately, I've never used Lucene before :( The Infinispan lock configuration does not affect Lucene locks.